# BOTO3 - generate_presigned_url for `put_object` return `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided`

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to create a presigned url that will help some customers to upload files .
Here my test script that is currently working

```
# Get the service client.
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
boto3.set_stream_logger(name='botocore')

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='put_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': s3_bucket_name,
        'Key': test_key,
    }    
)

files = StringIO("asdfasdfasdf")
response = requests.put(url, data=files)

print(str(response.content))
```

But if I'm adding:

```
`ACL': 'public-read'
```

to `Params` (or add some metadata following the information in the [put_object documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) I receive back from the server:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

---

I've open also a issue on BOTO3:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1722

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in the github issue https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/934

> For uploading an object, you should use [generate_presigned_post](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post). There are several parameters that cannot be embedded within the url, and those are returned to you by that method.

Answer (score 9):

Got the same problem using S3 on Dell ECS object storage. The S3 protocol is implemented partially so there's no support for POST method with ECS. 
The workaround is to use correct headers in PUT methtod, then the ACL for the object are set correctly on the server.

```
    # Get the service client.
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    boto3.set_stream_logger(name='botocore')

    # Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': s3_bucket_name,
            'Key': test_key,
            'ACL': 'public-read'
        }    
    )

    files = StringIO("asdfasdfasdf")
    headers = {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'}
    response = requests.put(url, data=files, headers=headers)

    print(str(response.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue finally found a great video on youtube, you can watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfDZKmL_PNo

or do this:

```
def download_generate_pre_signed_url(self, key, expires_sec: int = 3600):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    res = client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={'Bucket': self.__bucket_name, 'Key': key},
        ExpiresIn=expires_sec)
    return res

def upload_generate_pre_signed_url_post(self, key, expires_sec: int = 3600):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    res = client.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket=self.__bucket_name,
        Key=key,
        ExpiresIn=expires_sec)
    return res
```