# PreSigned URL uploads to new S3 Buckets will fail - eg 10054 on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Our CI/CD creates new S3 buckets, then generates pre-signed urls, and another system uploads to them

This fails about 90% of the time - S3 closes the socket at the start of the upload.

On Windows this shows as:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

After much investigation, this only happens on newly created s3 buckets, and seems to be a known but undocumented issue with S3

- https://repost.aws/questions/QUbDd-vC1lRgmMqgcR73GAIQ/anyone-seen-issues-with-new-s-3-buckets-and-presigned-ur-ls
- https://repost.aws/questions/QUZ_gRX6EoT2qIGoG66n4UDw/recent-created-bucket-doesnt-support-sigv-4-presigned-url

Has anyone found a way to get presigned urls to work with new s3 buckets?

Comment: S3 buckets in which region? And does it then work as per the first link? Does the issue happen via the SDK and CLI, crossing out any SDK issues? Have you tried other regions? And are the systems that are generating the pre-signed URL and uploading using it in the same timezone (out of curiosity)? Are you using invalid or expired credentials by any chance? Try using `aws s3 presign` and validate it. It may also be beneficial to provide exact troubleshooting steps i.e. using IaC so that we could perhaps recreate the problem?

Comment: Neither one of those URLs describes the scenario you're seeing.  Do you have any more debugging details?  Does it always work with an existing bucket?  Are the signing keys short lived?  Can you create a [mre] showing the failure?

Comment: I'll reply with the answer below shortly, but this was happening in testing in us-east-2 and us-west-1 (it looks like us-east-1 is the only region that doesn't have this issue)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed after following the advice in [S3 presigned URL works 90 minutes after bucket creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517156/s3-presigned-url-works-90-minutes-after-bucket-creation?rq=1), in particular I had to set both the region AND the regional endpoint to S3

i.e. This did not work:

```
cli = self.new_client(config=BotoConfig(use_dualstack_endpoint=True, signature_version="s3v4"))
```

This did work:

```
endpoint_url = f"https://s3.{region}.amazonaws.com"
cli = self.new_client(region=region, endpoint_url=endpoint_url, config=BotoConfig(use_dualstack_endpoint=True, signature_version="s3v4"))
```