# presigned URL : Post image error: Signature does not match: Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

1. I would execute the below in lambda to generate the presigned URL

'''

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': 'XXX-profile',
            'Key': 'test',
            'ContentType': 'image/jpeg',
             'ACL': 'public-read'},
        ExpiresIn=600
    )
    return url
```

'''
2. Once i get URL, I am trying to post the image from postman
[image]

Could you please help where is my mistake.. i could not find.

Comment: how are you passing the body `binary`?

Comment: Does this help? [*python - BOTO3 - generate_presigned_url for `put_object` return `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided` - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625812/boto3-generate-presigned-url-for-put-object-return-the-request-signature-we)

Comment: I used to add a file in body of postman

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `ACL` and `Content-Type` from the `Params`. These won't work with `generate_presigned_url` method.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': 'XXX-profile',
            'Key': 'test',
            },
        ExpiresIn=600
    )
    return url
```

If you still want to set the content-type and ACL, try to use the `generate_presigned_post` method.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/934) GitHub link if creating pre-signed URL for uploading