# BOTO3 - S3 - generate_presigned_url for `put_object` returns `SignatureDoesNotMatch`

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to create a presigned URL to upload a JSON object, but when I try to upload an object with this URL, it is denied with a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error code.

```
def get_put_presigned_url():
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response  = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod = 'put_object',
        Params = {
            'Bucket': "my-bucket",
            'Key': "test.json",
            'ContentType': 'application/json'
        },
        ExpiresIn = 3600,
        HttpMethod = 'PUT'
    )
    return response
```

If I change the method to `get_object`, the url works, so I am wondering if I need other settings for PUT requests. I tried adding more params like `ContentType` and `HttMethod` but it didn't change the error.

I tried looking at other similar issues like [BOTO3 - generate_presigned_url for `put_object` return `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625812/boto3-generate-presigned-url-for-put-object-return-the-request-signature-we), but couldn't find one that fix the issue.

Comment: Did you try generate_presigned_post?

Comment: Check this [solution](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/934#issuecomment-1018986702)

Comment: I cannot use `generate_presigned_post` because the client that uses the presigned URL is using PUT.

I did try the solution you linked but it doesn't work.

Comment: @GuillaumeMonzerol what was the error?

Comment: The error is `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Comment: I found out what my issue was. The code snippet in the question works. It originally failed because I had to add the `ContentType` param. After that it only failed because the content-type header was set to `text/plain` in postman.

Comment: Great to know you got it working! Feel free to add your own Answer to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my issue was. The code snippet in the question works. It originally failed because I had to add the `ContentType` param. After that it only failed because the content-type header was set to text/plain in postman.